# How to add image for image field for a model instance in django admin panel on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I added a few books on heroku data. Every model is displayed on heroku app site with its image. My models have the field "image". I take these images from my PC folder and when I open this app after 2-3 hours the book images dissapear. I think it's because I turn off a PC, where I took these images. How do I have to do it correctly that these images don't dissapear?

Answer (score 0):

> I think it's because I turn off a PC, where I took these images

This probably is not it, because Heroku doesn't have access to the files on your computer.

---

When you upload a file to the Django admin, it looks at the `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` settings configuration to determine how to store that file. [By default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-file-storage), it uses [`django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage), which means that it is writing those uploaded files to the dyno's filesystem at the location defined by [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT).

The issue is, dynos are ephemeral, and they can be destroyed, restarted, and moved without any warning, [which replaces your filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). This means that those uploaded files are just deleted without a trace, but the `ImageField` reference still thinks they are there.

The solution to this issue is to update the project's `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` to use something permanent, such as an *s3-compatible object store*. In Heroku & Django land, a common solution is to use [`django-storages`](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) alongside [Heroku's Bucketeer add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bucketeer). This solution uploads your files to a persistent data store that survives dyno restarts, instead of writing to the dyno file system which gets deleted frequently.

I know that this can be daunting, so I wrote up [this article](https://dev.to/heroku/properly-managing-django-media-static-files-on-heroku-o2l) with a pretty good write-up of the Heroku + Bucketeer process.

Comment: Hi Dan, I followed your guide but am receiving an error that no such directory or file exists when I try to access a file after uploading it. The way I upload is by sending the image in base64 from the frontend to my DRF endpoint.  I looked through the project files on github but didn't see any views that would help me out as to how I'm meant to upload the files. Thanks for the article and I'd appreciate it if you have any insight for my issue.